# Deserialize json to entity and associated entities

Tags: rest, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

JSON:

```
{
    "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
    "userProfile": {
        "firstName": "First Name",
        "lastName": "Last Name"
    }
}
```

In controller:

```
$user = $this->get('jms_serializer')->deserialize($request->getContent(), 'My\TestBundle\Entity\User', 'json');
print_r($user);
```

Result:

```
My\TestBundle\Entity\User Object
(
    [id:My\TestBundle\Entity\User:private] => 
    [email:My\TestBundle\Entity\User:private] => myemail@gmail.com
    [userProfile:My\TestBundle\Entity\User:private] => 
)
```

I don't understand why UserProfile entity is empty even though I provided first and last names. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to JMS serializer documentation:

@SerializedName
"This annotation can be defined on a property to define the serialized name for a property. If this is not defined, the property will be translated from camel-case to a lower-cased underscored name, e.g. camelCase -> camel_case."
http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#serializedname

So, I should use @SerializedName annotation to force it to use camelCase instead of underscore.